# Can thumb interwork be deactivated on CW 10.6 with ARM toolchain?

Tags: assembly, crash, cortex-m, thumb, codewarrior

I am working on a project with the CodeWarrior for `MCU v10.6 IDE`. It is an Eclipse based IDE from NXP. The project targets a K21 SoC from NXP (precisely a `MK21FN1M0M12`, which embeds a `cortex-m4`, `armv7-m`).
CodeWarrior is configured to use the ARM toolchain.

I am running into a crash related to thumb-interwork. This feature is enabled by the IDE and cannot be deactivated.

Since `armv7-m` only supports thumb2, using thumb-interwork does not seem to make sense in the first place. But I probably am missing something here.
All the code is properly generated in thumb instructions.

I get trouble when making an indirect function call, through a pointer. The function code gets an odd address at link stage, which is OK (this indicates it is thumb code). However, when calling it through a pointer, a BLX instruction gets generated (I suppose the linker updates the original BL into a BLX here) AND the function pointer's value remains even! Since the pointer's value is even, the jump instructs the core to switch to ARM mode. Hence the crash.

I think the linker upgrades the BL into a BLX because of the thumb-interwork feature being activated. On CodeWarrior for `MCU v10.6`, this is forced, I cannot disable it. I am told that this is "required for processor" by the tool and cannot click the related checkbox (`Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings`, ARM CPU. The processor is set to `"cortex-m4"`).

I do not understand why, since this is `armv7-m`. Moreover it seems to lead me into trouble. I think I am missing something here.

Could you please help me understand what is going on and/or tell me if there is a way to disable thumb-interwork on CodeWarrior?

Thanks and best regards,

Pierre

Comment: Disabling Thumb interworking will break _every_ function call (the tools aren't forcing it on just for giggles). This is a bit of an XY problem, and you've got the wrong Y. Can you give a complete [mcve] of actual problematic code?

Comment: Thank you @Notlikethat for your comment. Sorry to ask, but why would disabling thumb interworking break function calls? In other words, why are `bx` / `blx` required? I am going to try to produce such an example out of the project which is quite large.

Comment: I think I have answered my question from my previous comment. According to ARM's information about `bl` and `blx`, only the latter can use a register as operand. Thus I now understand why `blx` is required and why removing thumb-interworking would break function calls.

Comment: Well, in truth it's more that I misremembered the finer details of exactly which instructions are interworking or not :) The reality of what I had in mind is that you could only avoid interworking by targeting the obsolete pre-Thumb-2 TPCS ABI, which simply isn't supported on M-profile (the AAPCS ABI, which is inherently interworking, is effectively baked into the architecture). Anyway, I suspect the real problem lies in your C code, because the fact that the thing you're calling isn't a real function pointer (which _would_ have the lsb set) smells of undefined behaviour from typecasts.

Comment: Thank you @Notlikethat for your response. I appreciate your help! I think you are right, something must be wrong in the C code. I have tried to reproduce the problem with a prototype but did not succeed yet.
The idea is to store a function pointer inside a struct ("event handler"), along with a pointer to its argument. Those structs are stored inside a table.
`typedef struct
{
    int (*fct)(void *param);
    void *param;
} event_item_t;`
The `fct` pointer is wrong when calling a `register` function like:
`int event_register(int id, int (*fct)(void *), void *param)`
`fct` is even

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Notlikethat was right, my question was a bit of an XY problem.

My problem arose from using libraries built with GCC with CodeWarrior configured to use the Freescale's toolchain (ARM tools).

The function pointer with the LSB **not** set came from one of those libraries and was valued at the link stage by CodeWarrior.
Since the linker properly put every function from those libs at odd addresses, I guessed that it should miss some information to detect that the faulty pointer was actually a function pointer.

Long story short, it turned out that the libraries were stripped, especially with the `--strip-unneeded` flag. I removed that flag and the linker did a perfect job!